# How to remove complete word if it contain certain characters in python

Tags: python

I wanted to remove word in a sentence if word starts or contains certain chars.

Ex:

```
string_s = '( active parts ) acetylene cas89343-06-6'
```

if word contains or starts with cas remove entire word from string

```
input1 =  '( active parts ) acetylene cas89343-06-6'
output1 = '( active parts ) acetylene'

input2 = '( active parts ) acetylene th.cas1345'
output2 = '( active parts ) acetylene'
```

Comment: `" ".join(word for word in string_s.split(" ") if "cas" not in word)`

Comment: you would probably use regular expressions or even more simple if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub` with the pattern `\b[\w-]*cas[\w-]*\b`, and replace with a single space, then trim the output:

```
string_s = '( active parts ) acetylene cas89343-06-6'
output = re.sub(r'\b[\w-]*cas[\w-]*\b', ' ', string_s).strip()
print(string_s + '\n' + output)
```

This prints:

```
( active parts ) acetylene cas89343-06-6
( active parts ) acetylene
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by:-

```py
string = "hello how are you"
character = "a"
newString = []
for i in string.split(' '):
    if not character in i:
        newstring.append(i)
newString = ' '.join(newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
' '.join([*filter(lambda x: "cas" not in x, input1.split())])
```